# Data-Toggle not working bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to add data-toggle and data-target to a class but it's not working. I've made a html file that uses javascript, css, and bootstrap. 
This is the code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Portfolio</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
          <img src="img/profile pic.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8">
          <div class="d-flex flex-column">
            <div class="p-5 bg-dark text-white">
              <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <h1 class="display-4"> Jordan Rai </h1>
                <div> <i class="fa fa-github  fa-2x"></i> </div>
                <div> <i class="fa fa-linkedin-square  fa-2x"></i> </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="p-3 text-white bg-black">
              Student (Senior) at the Pennslyvania State University
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex flex-row text-center text-white align-items-start">
              <div class="p-4 bg-success font-div" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#home">
                <i class="fa fa-home  fa-2x d-block"></i> Home
              </div>
              <div class="p-4 bg-danger font-div">
                <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap  fa-2x d-block"></i> Resume
              </div>
              <div class="p-4 bg-primary font-div">
                <i class="fa fa-folder  fa-2x d-block"></i> Projects
              </div>
              <div class="p-4 bg-warning font-div">
                <i class="fa fa-envelope  fa-2x d-block"></i> Contact
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="collapse id=" id="home">
      <div class="p-5 text-white bg-success">
        <h2>My Resume</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container ">
    <footer class="p-5 bg-dark text-center ">
      <button class="btn ">
      <i class="fa fa-download fa-2x d-block "></i> Download
     </button>
    </footer>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js " integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN " crossorigin="anonymous "></script>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js "></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js "></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js "></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js " integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN " crossorigin="anonymous "></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js " integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q " crossorigin="anonymous "></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js " integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl " crossorigin="anonymous "></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm not sure if this is an issue of the order of the dependencies and .js files in the code. But when I run the file "home" does not have a collapsible bar.

Comment: Why do you have multiple versions of script files at the bottom of the body? For example you have `jquery` 3.2.1 and then you also include `jquery` 3.3.1. You have `bootstrap` 4.1.3 and then you later include `bootstrap` 4.0.0 again. WHY!

Comment: Just testing the different versions to see what was working. When I ran the file there was a single version of each. But the issue was resolved.